# Rare error in Symfony2 with "Resource Bundle"

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, resourcebundle

I have an application in Symfony2, and I get this error when I try to enter in one section, but if my partner uses the same code, for him all works fine. The error is:

> ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "ResourceBundle" from the global namespace in ...\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Intl\ResourceBundle\Reader\BinaryBundleReader.php line 31. Did you forget a use statement for this class?

Any Idea?
Thanks!

-- Edit --

I solved this issue by changing a field from money type to integer type. Any idea what was the problem?

Comment: It may be a bug which was fixed in a later Symfony version

Answer (score 1):

I guess your answer lies in this post:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonata-users/atwiFRuhNdY

The moneyType seems to use the internationalization setting. Which might explain why your partner is able to use the same code and you're not. It's in the php settings

Answer (score 0):

this error says that where you are using the class `BinaryBundleReader` you forgot to include it.

You can do it this way:

`use Symfony\Component\Intl\ResourceBundle\Reader\BinaryBundleReader;`

Comment: Thanks, but, where I need to do this?

Comment: are you somewhere using the class `BinaryBundleReader`?

Comment: No, this is the problem, I'm not using this class

Comment: I solved this issue changing in a form type, money type for integer type. Any idea was the problem?